# How to verify and publish a contract address source code to withdraw erc2o tokens

Tags: remix, cpp-ethereum

Created a contract sometimes back while playing with eth contracts tutorials, by mistake I sent some some erc20 tokens only to later loose control of the creator address. Stuck between letting it go and finding my way to publish and verify the source code from without having access to the address I used to create the contract.

Basically I want to be able to push some code such that the contract has a function I can call to withdraw the tokens to an address I controls while paying gas fees. More of have a field to enter the erc20 token address and another field to fill in the address I want the tokens sent to

Here's a screengrab of the supposed to be write contract tab.

Any assistance would be appreciated, as well I'd be willing to tip some $$ for a working code and steps.

[image: A screenshot of the contract address I want to publish a source code.]

Edited: I want to publish a source code that will allow me to withdraw erc20 tokens sent to this contract address. I want to have 2 fields where I can enter, the erc20 token contract address and the recipient address.

Comment: Try to explain you better, honestly I can not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please explain your question with any code reference or screenshots if possible.